# Tensorflow: How to keep same names in two independent graphs?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, graph

I've got a python script which generates graphs like the following both:
[image: two graph instances]
Now I'd like to initialize variables by their names:

```
sess.run(g1.initializer_op, feed_dict = {
    g1.graph.get_tensor_by_name("sample_data:0"): [1,2,3,4]
})
```

Therefore, I need all variables to be named equally in all graph instances
However, at the moment each variable in the second graph gets a "_1" suffix.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two different variables can't have the same name in tensorflow. That is why tensorflow adds "_1" to all variables which name already exists. If you want to use identical variables for all graphs, you have to create that variables in a `tf.variable_scope` and set `reuse=True` for each Graph you create after the first one.